# Passing contents of array from one class to another

Tags: iphone

I've got an array populating a small tableView in a DetailView class, and when the user presses a button I need the array to be sent to another View Controller, to populate a tableView there, but I'm having some difficulty getting it working. This is what I've been trying to do so far:

```
*DetailViewController.m*

    #import "DetailViewController.h"
    #import "OtherViewController.h"


-(IBAction) toCart:(id)sender {

    OtherViewController *oVC = [[OtherViewController alloc] init];
    oVC.shoppingList = sList;
    NSLog(@"Ingredients count %d", [sList count]); //This returns a number, so the sList definitely contains values, and the method is definitely being called.
    [oVC release];

}
```

---

```
*OtherViewController.m*

    #import "OtherViewController.h"
    #import "DetailViewController.h"

    @synthesize shoppingList;

-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"list count: %d", [shoppingList count]); // This returns 0

}
```

sList is populated elsewhere in the class, and sList and shoppingList are both declared in their respective .h files, with @property (nonatomic, retain)...

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: when do you navigate to other view? in didselect method of tableView?

Comment: No, sorry I probably should have mentioned. OtherViewController is on another tab of a tab bar.

Comment: IS it topViewController of that tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are having `taBbarcontroller`, so you can proceed as follows :

Create references of your you `viewControllers`(which are associated with `tabbar` as `topViewController`) in your `appDelegate`.

```
otherViewController = [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:<tabIndex>] topViewController];
```

make it as @property in appDelegate so that you can access it anywhere in your app.

now,

```
-(IBAction) toCart:(id)sender {

    //appDelegate <--- get reference to your application delegate using [[UIApplication sharedApplicaiton]delegate] do not forget to properly type cast it.

    OtherViewController *oVC = [appDelegate otherViewController];
    oVC.shoppingList = sList;
    NSLog(@"Ingredients count %d", [sList count]); 
//This returns a number, so the sList definitely contains values, and the method is definitely being called.
   // [oVC release]; no need to release it...

}


//also make sure you do not initialize shoppingList of otherViewController in viewDidLoad(or any other method) of otherViewController, else it will be overwritten(lost its previous reference).
```

in your `appDelegate's .h` write

```
@property OtherViewController *otherViewController;
```

in `appDelegate's.m`

```
@synthesize otherViewController;
```

in `appDelegates`'s .`m` (method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: ) write

```
otherViewController = [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:<tabIndex>] topViewController];
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok I think I understand, but I'm not sure where in my AppDelegate to put the 
otherViewController = [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:<tabIndex>] topViewController]; line and how to declare it as @property. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for updating the code! But when I put @property OtherViewController *otherViewController; into the .h file I get the error "Unknown type name 'OtherViewController'. Is there supposed to be something else in there or am I just being an idiot?
Also, what goes in the <tabIndex> part? It is the third tab along, so do I simply put '2' (assuming the index starts at 0)?
Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: you need to  add OtherViewController.h in your appDelegate's .h file.

Comment: You know I thought that's what I needed to do ;)

Works like a charm, thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In `toCart:`, you are creating an `OtherViewController` and then immediately throwing it away. Whatever `OtherViewController` is calling `-viewWillAppear`, it isn't the one you're creating in `toCart:`. How is that object created and put on the screen? You need a pointer to it to modify it.

Better, though, would be to move your model data out of the view controllers and put it in a single `ShoppingCart` object. Then all your view controllers would have a reference to it (or you can make `ShoppingCart` a singleton if that makes sense in your program). This way, any time you change the shopping cart from anywhere, all views will correctly update without having to tell every view controller about every other view controller.

Comment: I thought that by creating an instance of OtherViewController, and then setting the shoppingList array (which populates the table view in OVC) as the sList array, it would populate it in the OtherViewController class?

Comment: I believe you have a misunderstanding between classes and instances. You can create many instances of a class, and each one is independent. Creating one and modifying it doesn't modify others. You have one OtherViewController which is acting as a controller for your table view. That has nothing to do with the OVC you created in toCart:.